# Calling Drawrect manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I am creating a custom view with `UIBezierPath` drawing. I want to update the custom view fill color whenever state changes based on response from server. I am using `fillColor` property as a param to update view's color. How can i change the `fillcolor` programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

You must *never* call `drawRect`. Instead, call `setNeedsDisplay`, and `drawRect` will be called for you. As for changing the color, it's just a matter of planning ahead — put the color where your `drawRect` routine can find it. Thus, for example, if you have a property holding the fill color, you can change that and call `setNeedsDisplay`, and the view can thus be redrawn using the new fill color property value.

Comment: Matt speaks truth (as usual). Calling drawRect yourself is not allowed. It will "warp your mind, curve your spine, and make the enemy win the war", to paraphrase George Carlin.